# addEventListener don't seems to be working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, cordova

I am a new phonegap user and I am trying out this compass tutorial that I found on youtube.

Everything seems to be working well except that the needle of the compass is not moving.

Well, I am thinking that my addEventListener is not working somehow.

I am not sure why exactly as well.

Any help?

My project file structure

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nBdIvgK.png]

**Link to my project files for easier viewing**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7-DKery9JL4Q2VWMUlaY08tREk/edit?usp=sharing

My codes are located below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.compass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>&nbsp;</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            #compass {

                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            #needle {

                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                left: 98px;
                z-index: 10;
            }

        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="jqRotate/jqRotate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <img src="http://nathanhedglin.us/images/compass.png" id="compass">
        <img src="http://nathanhedglin.us/images/needle.png" id="needle">
    </body>
</html>
<script>

function onDeviceReady() { 
    alert("Starting!");
        startCompass(); //runs the startCompass function
    }

    function onLoad() {
    alert("Loading!!");
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); //creates a listener that waits for the deviceready event and then fires onDevice ready function
    }

    function startCompass() {

        var options = {
            frequency : 50 //sets the compass heading to be updated every 50 milliseconds
        };

        navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options); //gets the compass heading from device and passes heading to onSuccess function
        alert("Compass starting!!");
    }

    function onSuccess(heading) {//device s magnetic heading is passed to heading variable

        $("#needle").rotate(-heading.magneticHeading); //jquery function that gets the #needle id and rotates it minus the current heading
    }

    function onError(compassError) { //if there is an error the error will be passed to onError in the compassError variable
        alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code); //displays an alert with the error code
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the deviceready inside the onLoad because the deviceready is fired before onLoad. And personally I recommend staying away from using onLoad with PhoneGap.

Your head should look something like this:

```
// All of your scripts loaded above

<script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    // This is where you should initialize your application
  }
</script>
```

deviceready should be the very first thing you add and then any other event listeners should be added after deviceready has fired.